# Change LISTAGG values from one table based on dataset from another table

Tags: sql, oracle11gr2, listagg

I need to send data to users who sign up for events. These events occur when a state is removed or added to a list of states associated with a group.

Some context: My data has groups, and each group has a list of states that are called sublead states. Groups can have as many or as few sublead states as they want/need.

So group 1 can have IA, WY, and NY as subleads, or it could have just IA, or it could have none.

My question involves 3 different tables.

- Table called `group_sublead_state` that holds entries for each sublead state belonging to a group
- An audit table called `sublead_state_audit` that holds the information for when a sublead state is added or removed from a group
- The table called `sublead_change_results` that will appear in the user email when a state they are subscribed to is removed from or added to a groups sublead state list (This table is what should be the results of my query. I cannot create this table, do inserts, deletes, or updates. This is strictly the results of a big long ugly select query that mashes together the other two tables, along with a couple of tables that hold other information like group names and such (other tables not relevant))

Here are the tables with some data:

group_sublead_state

```
group_id    state
1           IA
1           WY
2           NY
2           OH
2           NV
```

This table tells us there are two groups, one with two sublead states, one with three sublead states

Here's the sublead_state_audit table

```
group_id    state_added    state_removed
1           none           MO
1           IA             none
2           NY             none
2           OH             none
2           none           CA
```

We see from the audit table that the most recent changes are that

- group_id 1 had MO removed, and IA added
- group_id 2 had NY and OH added, and CA removed

So the sublead_change_results table must look like the following

```
group_id    old_states    new_states
1           MO,WY         IA,WY
2           CA,NV         NY,OH,NV
```

So the new_states column is fairly simple, and I've already completed it using the `LISTAGG` function (we'll call that list for each group `current_state_list`). The old_states column though...this is where I need help.

I have to use the resources from these tables to compile the comma separated list in the old_states column. So far, my thought is to try and use the logic already built for the new_states column. So, for each group_id, I will remove states from the `current_states_list` that are in the state_added column of the `sublead_state_audit` table; and I will add states to the `current_states_list` that are in the state_removed column of the `sublead_state_audit`.

Is that at all possible with LISTAGG? Is there another way I can do it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select x.group_id,
       x.old_states,
       y.new_states
  from (select group_id,
               listagg(state, ',') within group(order by state) as old_states
          from (select group_id,
                       state_removed as state
                  from sublead_state_audit
                 where state_removed <> 'none'
                union all
                select group_id,
                       state
                  from group_sublead_state
                 where state not in (select state_added from sublead_state_audit))
         group by group_id) x
  join (select group_id,
               listagg(state, ',') within group(order by state) as new_states
          from group_sublead_state
         group by group_id) y
    on x.group_id = y.group_id;
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2921e/1/0

Comment: I believe you solved my problem! Working on checking it out now. Will mark this as the solution once I'm done.